# Select() with Non-Blocking I/O and Select() with Blocking I/O in socket

Tags: sockets, select, nonblocking

I am trying to understand select() and non-blocking I/O concept. 
but still not got what will happen if use Blocking I/O with select() and what about if use non-blocking with select().

I read, select() is already block call. then how does it works?

Answer (score 0):

> what will happen if use Blocking I/O with `select()`

You will get an `IllegalBlockingModeException.`

> `select()` is already block call. then how does it works?

It blocks until an event that is being selected on occurs, or the timeout expires, if any.

Comment: At least on UNIX systems it is perfectly valid to use select with blocking sockets and it is also perfectly valid to use select with languages like C which have no supports for Exceptions at all. Maybe the behavior you describe is specific to Java.

Comment: Somehow the answer assumes Java, which was not specified in the question.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But still have some doubt. I am not able to clear blocking and non-blocking context.

1) What is difference if use Blocking read/write with multiple client with select or Non-blocking with select()?<br/> 2) Where will i get issue if use bocking or non-blocking with select or without select in BSD socket in c

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to use `select()` or `poll()` with blocking or non-blocking sockets. Call to `select()` itself will be blocked until (one of the) socket(s) provided to `select()` will become available for reading.